# Pause command if not succeeded instead of automatically closing

Tags: windows, batch-file, command

Lets say I want to copy a file or run a program, but the file or the location is not found. How can I let my computer pause the command window when these kind of problems occure? I made a batch file to copy files to another location, but also to run programs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your batch script, use `xcopy` to do the actual copying, rather than the `copy` command - 
`xcopy`, unlike `copy`, returns error codes depending on the result of the copy, which are documented [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) in the remarks section.

As Aleksandr mentioned, you can use the error codes as part of your script to pause on error.
Assuming you would like to pause on all errors, you could do script this as below:

```
xcopy /HECY <source> <destination>
if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 pause
```

Obviously you'll need to replace  and  in the above with the locations you are copying from and to respectively.

The /HECY switches are just an example, but in this case could be used to instruct xcopy to copy hidden files, recurse directories, and automatically overwrite files in the destination if they exist. You can tweak these to your specific needs.

Comment: I just get "NOT was unexpected at this time." on the second line.  I would recommend "if %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 pause" instead.

Comment: I prefer doing it this way: `xcopy /HECY <source> <destination> || pause`

Answer (score 0):

Check the error code and pause if it is non zero